# run a task or code automatically every day

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony-1.4

I hope to limit the number of messages sent for users of my site develloped in sf 1.4, so the idea is to count for every user the number of messages sent for every day,so if a user exceed 10 messages for example then he can't send another message for this day he must wait until tomorrow.

I'm thinking to create a task and run it every day at midnight and put all number of messages for every user to 0, so my questions are :

- Do you think it's a good idea to realize it?
- Can someone now how to do to run a task or a code every 24 hours in symfony?

**edit**

Ok I have a cpanl on my server give me any tutorials to setup  a cron job or sample code of Task,I don't have any idea?

Comment: you should need to set up a cron job in the server for this...

Comment: The way you want to do it is a bad idea. ideally, you should record all the messages in a database table, together with the datetime it were sent. Then it's very easy with a simple query to get the number of messages sent on a specific day, today for example

Comment: @SherinJose  Bartdude  tnks for you answers,I make an edition in my first message above?

Comment: I don't agree that yours is an ideal solution @Bartdude. If you really only need the info of how many messages has been sent today then  OP's solution is a good one. Saving the data into a database will only be useful if you need access to past data. If the application is very big with many users sending many messages the database can quickly become very large and even simple select queries can impact performance.

Comment: @MichalTrojanowski so what's the good solution and what you mean OP's solution?

Comment: @Michal Trojanowski > I would hope someone working on such a big system as a simple select query on a probably indexed table would be very slow would know about cron jobs. Also, a very easy "archiving" solution could be put in place with the idea of OP to move records of today to another table. That way you keep possibly usefull data for the future. For example you could imagine that if someone hasn't sent any message one day, he could send more the next day, or anything...

Comment: I'm not saying keeping detailed data in a database is a bad solution. I just don't like the idea that "idealy you should keep record of all the send messages". If you don't need to you don't have to. And of course there are (nearly) endless options on keeping high performance of the system :)

Comment: @NabilEl OP is you :) (OP = Original Poster)

Answer (score 1):

A cron Job would solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The cron jobs helps you to run codes automaticallly on the server, go through the [link](http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/AllDocumentation/CpanelDocs/CronJobs)